# Copy 1 sql table to another with some additional data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
<?php
//MYSQL
$dbserver="..."; //adresa MySQL
$dblogin="...";       //jméno uživatele MySQL
$dbheslo="...";     //heslo MySQL
$dbnazev="...";      //název databáze MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbheslo, $dbnazev); 
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Nepodařilo se připojit k MySQL serveru (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); // nastavíme kódování MySQL



while($row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `importovat_fyz` WHERE `tempid` IS NOT NULL")->fetch_assoc()){

$tempid = $row['tempid'];
$jmeno = $row['jmeno'];
$prijmeni = $row['prijmeni'];


$email = $row['email'];
$bydliste = $row['bydliste'];

$souhlas = "on";
$aktuality = "on";

$timestamp = time();
$hash = md5("77c0a83besxxxcg1a190ab90d".time().$tempid.rand(10000000, 99999999));

$poznamky = "import19052018";

$vloz ="INSERT into `potvrzenotest` set jmeno='".$jmeno."', prijmeni='".$prijmeni."', bydliste='".$bydliste."', email='".$email."', souhlas='".$souhlas."', aktuality='".$aktuality."', timestamp='".$timestamp."', hash='".$hash."', poznamky='".$poznamky."';";
$result=$mysqli->query($vloz);


$cas = date('H:i');
echo '['.$cas.'] ID '.$tempid.' imported.', PHP_EOL;
}

mysqli_close($mysqli); .
?>
```

I have one table with some data and I have to copy it to another table with some additional data (like hash etc.).

When I run the code above, I got this:

```
[17:17] ID 1 imported.
[17:17] ID 1 imported.
[17:17] ID 1 imported.
[17:17] ID 1 imported.
[17:17] ID 1 imported.
```

So, only 1 row is being copied.

Could you please help me, where is the problem?

Comment: You have an endless loop.

Comment: Take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html for a simpler way to do this in one command

Comment: @apokryfos The data needs to be processed. And I know no **reliable** way in MySQL to replace `rand(10000000, 99999999)`.

Comment: mysql has random number generation functions

Comment: @apokryfos I edited my comment to highlight "**reliable**".

Comment: why is it unreliable?

Comment: @apokryfos "`RAND()` is not meant to be a perfect random generator. ... This function is unsafe for statement-based replication." ([mathematical-functions.html#function_rand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)). So without knowing the exact requirements (does it need to be cryptographically secure?) and the environment (replication) you can't just replace PHP's `rand()` with something like `FLOOR(RAND()*90000000)+10000000`. Alone `FLOOR` may lead to an unwanted distribution.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `rand` pre php 7 suffers from similar problems and post php7 uses marsene twister which is better but still not cryptographically secure .

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry - I mixed up `rand()` and `random_int()`. So a single `INSERT .. SELECT` statement might be fine. But still not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `importovat_fyz` WHERE `tempid` IS NOT NULL")->fetch_assoc()){ ... }
```

This loop will never end. And it will fetch the first row again and again.

You should execute the query outside the loop:

```
$selectResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `importovat_fyz` WHERE `tempid` IS NOT NULL");

while ($row = $selectResult->fetch_assoc()) { ... }
```

As a side note: Consider to use a [**prepared statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your INSERT statement in the loop. This will prevent SQL syntax errors if some of the values may contail special characters like `'`. If you run them in one [**transaction**](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.begin-transaction.php), you might even improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks. But there is error.

```php script_import.php 
 [12:29] ID 1 imported.
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function   fetch_assoc() on boolean in script_import.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in script_import.php on line 17```

Comment: @OndrejSimer Change the variable name `$result` in my code to something different. For example `$selectResult`. The error occurs because you are using the same variable for your insert statement in the loop.

Comment: I added this: ```echo "number of rows: " . $result->num_rows, PHP_EOL;``` for debugging and output is ```number of rows: 1460```... strange